# What is the word that best describes the transformation one goes through after having an epiphany?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word that best describes the transformation one goes through after having an epiphany?

My girlfriend swears there is a word for this besides epiphany, transformative, revelation, etc.  Is she possibly misremembering or is there a specific word for that?

Comment: Epiphany has [a lot of different meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epiphany): realising how to solve a (possibly minor) problem; having a major realisation about your life leading to a change in career or vocation; to the manifestation of a divine being.

Comment: Are you seeking a word that describes experiencing an epiphany or one that describes the effects of experiencing an epiphany? The former might be easier to narrow down than the latter since there is no singular response to an epiphany.

Answer (score 2):

You could say that the realization **remade** you, that you were **reborn,** or that it caused you to **reinterpret** things. You could say that the change was **tectonic.** If the realization was unpleasant, you could say that it **shook you to your core.**

Answer (score 1):

This might be a [Damascene moment](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Damascene_moment) or [Damascene conversion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Damascene_conversion). Both phrases allude to Paul's conversion to Christianity on the road to Damascus.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of ***transfiguration***:

> 1. a change in form or appearance (metamorphosis)
> 2. an exalting, glorifying, or spiritual change ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transfiguration))

[OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=transfiguration%20meaning&oq=trabsfig&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j0i10i433i512l2j0i10i512l2j0i10i433i512j0i10i512l4.4787j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) defines the word as

> a complete change of form or appearance into a more beautiful or spiritual state.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like she *had a breakthrough*.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/437483)

Comment: He's looking for a specific word. This is one that isn't mentioned by him or anyone else and thus could be an answer to his question.

Answer (score -1):

She might have made a quantum leap in understanding ...